# PJL (Printer Job Language) only works when printer is on-line

Tags: printing, pjl

During a telnet session to an HP JetDirect card using the printer's IP address / port 9100, commands such as:

```
@PJL INFO STATUS
```

are entered which get back

```
CODE=10001
DISPLAY="00 READY"
ONLINE=TRUE
```

But when the printer is taken off line there is no response to the PJL command.  There is also no response to the PJL command when a paper jam is reported from the printer's display. The goal is to write a script to determine if the printer has stopped printing because it is done or for other reasons such as a paper jam or an empty paper tray.  In the former case power will be cut to the printer.  But in the latter cases power will remain on so the situation can be resolved.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I've got an HP M601 that just doesn't respond to any PJL commands at all.

Comment: No, it appears when the printer is any of these states it does not relay that information to the JetDirect card.  Of course there are likely several versions of JetDirect cards and many compatible printers still operating.  So a different combination may be worth trying.  But I have never been able to do much beyond what is described above with what I have.